# Strange behavior of SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

In a Prolog program I execute the following SPARQL query that tells me whether, for a given name, there are some persons having this name (so if find more then 50 occurrences I consider this name as a proper name of person):

```
?- sparql_query('select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "Pescara"@it.}', Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')]).
false.
```

The problem is that today the output is always **FALSE**, and this is very strange because, until yesterday, it worked fine!  Now I tried also to execute it into [Virtuoso endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), but the application does not start, and gives me the following error message today:

> Virtuoso 08C01 Error CL...: Cluster could not connect to host 4 22204 error 111

Maybe this strange behavior depends on some DBpedia problems? Or could it be something else? Someone have similar problems?

Comment: You wrote “SPARQL query that say me if, given a name, there are some persons having this name (so if find more then 50 occurrences I consider this name as a proper name of person):”, but the query is asking for `?place a dbpedia-owl:Place` which is going to find `Place`s for you, not `Person`s.  Is this a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you can see in the web browser is the important part;  the server seems to have been down or unavailable when you tried connecting to it.  The query seems to run just fine and to return `1`.

```
select COUNT(*) where {
  ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
         rdfs:label "Pescara"@it.
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+COUNT%28%2a%29+where+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fplace+a+dbpedia-owl%3APlace+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%22Pescara%22%40it.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

If you are critically depending on being able to run live queries, you should consider the possibility of [downloading](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) the DBpedia data that you need and hosting in a local SPARQL endpoint such as [Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/).

Comment: host 4 of dbpedia goes offline from time to time, but is mostly back online a few hours later.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for adding that comment.  I've had intermittent outages that seemed to be resolved within a few minutes, but I didn't know the specific host.

Comment: just to make it clear. I'm not associated with the dbpedia Project, just a regular user.